# Draw only portion of a custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-draw

I have a custom view which is a `RelativeLayout` which contains a `ListView` (both are set to match parent - width and height).
On top of the list I have a `View` as seen in the picture below:
[image: My Custom View]

I want that the only part that will be drawn is the rect of my `View` (marked with gray), while all the other portion of the view will be transparent.

is there a way I can do this? 
I already tried to extend `RelativeLayout` and override its `onDraw()` method, but I didn't manage to draw only the specific region (marked in gray).

Comment: Are u looking for effect like this : http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Comment: @SourabSharma no.. I know this project and it's not what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I did it by extending `RelativeLayout` and override its `draw()` method.

```
@Override
protected void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.clipRect(magnifiedRegion.getLeft(), magnifiedRegion.getTop(), magnifiedRegion.getRight(), magnifiedRegion.getBottom());
    super.draw(canvas);
}
```

where `magnifiedRegion` is my View as it mentioned in the question above.

Note: you must set `this.setWillNotDraw(false);` in the constructor or else, `draw()` method won't be called by the framework (since our root view is a `ViewGroup` - it's an optimization Android framework does by default).